# Regex period matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I know that a `.` is a match any character in regex, but I'm a bit puzzled by these results and am hoping someone can explain them:

```
".".match("[+-\/]") //matches
".".match("[+\-\/]") //matches
".".match("[+\/]") //null
".".match("[\+\/]") //null
".".match("[-\/]") //null
".".match("[+-]") //null
```

What is so magical about `+-\/` that causes JS to go "yep, that looks like a period."?

Comment: So how does a period get matched when being compared to a plus sign, a negative, and a division?

Comment: He missed the point that . is the target, not the regex, but these results are a little bit strange.

Comment: `[+-\/]` means match all characters with ASCII values from `+` (2B) to `/` (2F)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII code for `+` is 43, `/` is 47.

`[+-\/]` match chracter range between `+` and `/`: `+`, `,`, `-`, `.`, `/`.; So `.` is matched.

---

Escaping `-` has no effect here.

```
"[+\-\/]" == "[+-/]" // => true.
```

You should use regular expression literal (`/[+\-\/]/`) if you want match only `+`, `-`, `/`. Or, escape `\` itself: `"[+\\-/]"` (You don't need  need escape `/` if you use string literal)

Comment: Thanks. Just a side equation: why doesn't escaping the - with \ stop it from acting as a range? Edit: ah, so it just ignores it.

Comment: @Rhyono, Updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: I'd suggest putting `-` first. Like `/[-+\/]/`

Answer (score 0):

Going just a little further than the answer above, you could use this expression `[--/]` to be even more specific (instead of matching between `+` and `/` which contains other possibilities, this is only between `-` and `/`.

Here is a quick example of what I am using this for - matching dollar amounts with decimals (while not capturing the currency sign):

Expression: `\d+[--/]\d{2}`

Matching something like: 110.30

I would just add this as a comment, but not enough rep yet.